# Compare frame of video with another image python?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I would like compare a frame of video with another image but i don't know how can i do it with python.
Someone can help me please

Comment: `[f1 == f2].all()`

Comment: This is really vague. What do you mean by compare?

Comment: What does "compare" mean to you?  There's lots of things it _could_ mean...

Answer (score 1):

You can use various metrics, look them up to see how they're calculated and when you should use them. In Python this can be achieved easily with [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/).

```py
import cv2
from skimage.measure import compare_mse, compare_nrmse, compare_ssim, compare_psnr

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

# mean squared error
compare_mse(img1, img2)
# normalized root-mean-square
compare_nrmse(img1, img2)
# peak signal-to-noise ratio
compare_psnr(img1, img2)
# structural similarity index
compare_ssim(img1, img2, multichannel=True)
```

The images must have the same size.